# Can selenium slow down or stop the windows server?

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python selenium script that runs after every 5 minutes inside the windows server and using a chrome driver. It takes 3-4 minutes to complete.
Is there any possibility that it causes the server to stop working or make it down?
because in my case it was running fine for 4-5 days after that, we found the server stop working and we require to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the browser with driver.quit() at the end of your script? Check if you have one multiple instances of chromedriver.exe running when your script is not actually running.

Comment: Yes After accomplishing my task I first use driver.close() followed by driver.quit().

Comment: If it is creating a problem can you please suggest what I need to do to resolve this.

Comment: What operating system are you using in your server? If there server crashed there should be a dump file with the error. I guess you are using Windows Server, you can try looking for that file at C:/Windows/memory